# How does my teacher know how many parameters to put in her closures and how does she know what type Swift will infer?

Tags: swift, firebase, parameters, firebase-authentication, closures

My teacher is including a closure in her user-authentication method. The closure takes two parameters. The method being called is `signIn(withEmail: String, password: String, completion: AuthDataResultCallBack?)` from Firebase.

Her code is below. How does she know the number of parameters that the closure needs and how does she know their types?:

```
@IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //TODO: Log in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Log in unsuccessful")
        }
        else {
            print("Log in successful")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `AuthDataResultCallBack`.

Comment: It’s not what the teacher knows. It’s what the compiler knows.

Comment: You asked a question, you got an answer. If it solved your problem, click the green check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rmaddy stated, check the documentation as a first step. If you don't feel like Googling it, you can press the command key and click on the the thing you're looking for and it'll take you to the definition.

[image]

Here's a [link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Type-Definitions#/c:FIRAuth.h@T@FIRAuthDataResultCallback)

Also, your teacher shouldn't be force unwrapping. If you have a nil parameter, an exception will be thrown and your app will crash. Additionally, if an error is thrown, while you're "in the neighborhood", rather than just printing there's an error, print what the error actually is and you eliminate some guesswork. Here's your method rewritten:

```
@IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //TODO: Log in the user
    guard
        let emailText = emailTextField.text,
        let passwordText = passwordTextField.text else { return }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailText, password: passwordText) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Log in unsuccessful:", error)
        }
        else {
            print("Log in successful")
        }
    }
}
```